# MVVM from where I should subscribe with Rx?

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, system.reactive, android-livedata

I come from the `MVP` pattern and now I'm using `MVVM` pattern and RXJava to do some features like the display in a map my current location. For this, I'm subscribing in my MV to a `Disposable` and I will get a `Location`:
(`t` is my location)

```
val subscription = locationProvider.lastKnownLocation
    .subscribe(Consumer { t -> updateLocationMap(t) })
```

My question is should I subscribe to this `Disposable` in my `View`? Because I see that `ViewModel` can't be instanced in the `View` and know I don't know how to use this `Location` object.

Comment: Use `Livedata` to listen to changes in ViewModel. And register you ViewModel in your view.

Comment: And then from where I should subscribe to my Disposable before transform it in LiveData?

Comment: Subscribe to it in your ViewModel. Then set the result to the LiveData's value

Comment: How you can see in my case when I subscribe to the Disposable it returns me the location ( t in that case ). You mean I have to create a LiveData<Location> and then in my subscribe made a LiveData<Location> = t ?

Comment: Do this: `val locLiveData = MutableLiveData<Location>()` in your `ViewModel` and then set the location as the livedata value `locLiveData.value = location` in your `subscrible()` function. After registering your viewmodel in your view, call the location livedata and start observing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

Create a variable in Viewmodel

```
    val LocationLiveData = MutableLiveData<Location>()
```

Below code should be in viewmodel

```
 disposable = locationProvider.lastKnownLocation
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe{location -> 
                LocationLiveData.postValue(location)
            }
```

After that in View( Activity )

```
 viewmodel.LocationLiveData.observe(this, { t: Location? -> 
   //use this updated location
  })
```

Comment: but should I call the function and return the LocationLiveData where I declare the postValue on the variable?

Comment: In onCreate method of activity observe the LocationLive data which is give you last updated location. Create a getter for LocationLiveData .